# extract instagram data with axios and ?__a=1 got blocked after half a day (1 request/minute)

Tags: javascript, json, axios, instagram, blocked

i wrote a script that retrieves a users profile data in json from `[response.data.graphql.user]`

I use this:

```
const response = await axios.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+accountUrl+'?__a=1');
```

For a list of users i want to loop this script and get all the data.
To not getting blocked i set a timer or 1 request per minute, but after a few hours i seem to have been blocked.

`request.response_url` returned: `https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/`
and `response.data.graphql` does not exists

Even over a VPN line it does not work anymore...

Does anyone have any idea what i can do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to login to Instagram and then send the request again. The best way would be to use something like puppeteer and log in before hitting the `?__a=1` endpoint.

You may also need to reduce increase the time for requests to something like 1 request / 3 minutes better to do a hit and trial run to find out the limit.